# Is there a way to dump the method definition in OOP/PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Just wondering if there is any way to dump and view the function/method definition inside the class using the Object name?

I found the way to get the class name and method name as well using an instantiated object name with this function:

```
public function getObjectMethods(object $obj) {
   $className = get_class($obj);
   //return $className;
   return get_class_methods($className);
}
```

Also, I could access the properties in the class by using the var_dump; however, is there any way I could see the method/function definition inside the class?

Comment: This might help https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

Comment: @TimMorton thanks for the response..it doesn't display the definition of the function..have already tried that one :(

Answer (score 0):

Well AFAIK, there is no such function to see what code written on the function directly. (well, you can get the function line number and read the file with `file_get_contents`)

Comment: @IIIya how do I use to read the core Php function? Let's say I want to read the $foo_obj->fetch_assoc(); (Mysqli Object Method) then how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Kint as a temporary option. It's uses reflection to deep dive into the class/object/instance.

https://github.com/kint-php/kint

`Kint::dump($obj);`

[image]